# Graph Application UML Class Diagram

Tags: class, graph, uml

I'm designing a UML class diagram for an application that makes graphs from data.
I have the application driver class itself, which reads in the data and then creates the graph.
I have a "Graph" class which has various attributes including an array of "Vertex" classes.
As mentioned above I also have the "Vertex" class which has attributes related to the node.

I'm trying to come up with the best way of representing the above.
Would it be correct to say that the "Graph" class is an aggregation of "Vertex" classes?
How should the driver class show that it creates graphs?
Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest you try drawing the class diagram yourself. Note also that rarely one diagram as well as one diagram type is enough for a single project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See picture below. Assuming each Vertex is part of only one Graph, I have used composition, the strong form of aggregation.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! My diagram looks very similar to that, except that I have a composition instead.I just have one follow up question - why is an aggregation more appropriate? Is it because a vertex cannot exist without a graph?  

My software creates the nodes inside the driver class and then calls a method on the Graph instance (eg: addVertex(Vertex: theVertex)) to add the vertex.

Comment: You should not care too much about shared/composite aggregation. It has to do with lifetime of elements depending on the aggregating element. It's usage adds more confusion than it actually helps understanding the model. Personally I think that the only real use of this diamond is with foreign key constraints and memory management.

Comment: Personally, I do not use the open diamond ('shared aggregation'), only the filled diamond ('composition'), to indicate a whole-part relationship, but only if the part-instances must be destroyed when the enclosing whole-instance is destroyed (in db terms: a cascading delete). In your case, use the composition if the vertices of a graph only exist as long as the graph exists. Otherwise, use a plain assocation. At least, that would be my advice.